How to deal with FMUException: FMUSlave failed to initialize due to illegal character '!'
I am trying a co-simulation of an FMU exported from an IDF file with PyFMI using a Python code. The FMU passed the validation process on fmi-standard.org. However, I get the error as mentioned in the object:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ~\OneDrive\Documents\simulation.py:28 in <module>
model.initialize(time, timestop, True)
File src\\pyfmi\\fmi.pyx:3142 in pyfmi.fmi.FMUModelCS1.initialize
FMUException: The slave failed to initialize. See the log for possibly more information.

Here is the content of the output.log file
=== Input Error ===
File C:\Users\AUDIO-~1\AppData\Local\Temp\JModelica.org\jm_tmpv9m6k_r4\resources\heatrecovery.idf,
line 10: Encountered illegal character '!' while reading a token.

I checked the idf, but still can't fix the problem. I will appreciate any help on this.
Thank you.
Theodore.

The online checker does just a static validation.
Please use also one of the other checkers listed on https://fmi-standard.org/validation/ such as fmpy or fmusim to actually simulate the fmu.
(Please add the "fmi" tag)
